# Match conditionally upon current node value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xmlnode

Given the following XML:

```
<current>
  <login_name>jd</login_name>
</current>
<people>
  <person>
    <first>John</first>
    <last>Doe</last>
    <login_name>jd</login_name>
  </preson>
  <person>
    <first>Pierre</first>
    <last>Spring</last>
    <login_name>ps</login_name>
  </preson>
</people>
```

How can I get "John Doe" from within the current/login matcher?

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
  <xsl:value-of select="../people/first[login_name = .]"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="../people/last[login_name = .]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd define a key to index the people:

```
<xsl:key name="people" match="person" use="login_name" />
```

Using a key here simply keeps the code clean, but you might also find it helpful for efficiency if you're often having to retrieve the `<person>` elements based on their `<login_name>` child.

I'd have a template that returned the formatted name of a given `<person>`:

```
<xsl:template match="person" mode="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(first, ' ', last)" />
</xsl:template>
```

And then I'd do:

```
<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('people', .)" mode="name" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Okay, ignore my answer further down, this one is great. Clean and made up of nice reusable parts.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) function

```
<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
  <xsl:value-of select="../../people/person[login_name = current()]/first"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="../../people/person[login_name = current()]/last"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or a bit more cleaner:

```
<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
  <xsl:for-each select="../../people/person[login_name = current()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="first"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="last"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thx for the current tip ... even if i really dislike the usage of for-each in xslt ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access multiple users, then [JeniT's `<xsl:key />` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995/xslt-and-xpath-match-conditionally-upon-current-node-value#62429) is ideal.

Here is my alternative take on it:

```
<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
    <xsl:variable name="person" select="//people/person[login_name = .]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($person/first, ' ', $person/last)" />
</xsl:template>
```

We assign the selected `<person>` node to a variable, then we use the `concat()` function to output the first/last names.

There is also an error in your example XML. The `<person>` node incorrectly ends with `</preson>` (typo)

A better solution could be given if we knew the  overall structure of the XML document (with root nodes, etc.)

Comment: thanks for the tip ... works great ... i don't know why, i just dislike using variables in xslt ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what he actually wanted was the replacement in the match for the "current" node, not a match in the person node:

```
<xsl:variable name="login" select="//current/login_name/text()"/>

<xsl:template match="current/login_name">
<xsl:value-of select='concat(../../people/person[login_name=$login]/first," ", ../../people/person[login_name=$login]/last)'/>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my thoughts to the stack

```
<xsl:template match="login_name[parent::current]">
 <xsl:variable name="login" select="text()"/>
 <xsl:value-of select='concat(ancestor::people/child::person[login_name=$login]/child::first/text()," ",ancestor::people/child::person[login_name=$login]/child::last/text())'/>
</xsl:template>
```

I always prefer to use the axes explicitly in my XPath, more verbose but clearer IMHO.

Depending on how the rest of the XML documents looks (assuming this is just a fragment) you might need to constrain the reference to "ancestor::people" for example using "ancestor::people[1]" to constrain to the first people ancestor.